# jquery load is executed before jquery read

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a main page with a div tag that is used to load dynamically (using [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) a bootstrap modal (an independent html file).

I'm passing parameters to that page using the "complete" function of load. When the complete function executes I set some hidden parameters in the modal html. That modal html refers to another javascript file that has a [JQuery ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to initialize the modal with the parameters I set in the main page (using "complete" function).

The problem is that the "complete" executes after the modal html and the modal javascript is loaded, so I can't have an appropriate initialization. Therefore, I need to be sure that the modal javascript is executed just after the "complete" function is executed on the main page.

It is a large project but basically this is the code:

main-page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>main-page</title>
        <script src="./jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./main-page.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/predial/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Maing Page</h4>
        <button id="load-modal">Load Modal</button>
        <div id="holder">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main-page.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load-modal").click(function(){
        $("#holder").load("modal.html", function(){
            $("#parameter").val("a value");
        });
    });
}
);
```

modal.html (for sake of clarity I don't use bootstrap modals in this example)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="modal.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="parameter" name="parameter" type="text" value="uninitilized"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

modal.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parameter = $("#parameter").val();
    alert(parameter);
}    
);
```

If you try the code when alert pops out, it shows "uninitilized" instead of "a value" ¿Any suggestions?

Comment: share your code/working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just save function to memory (to any var) on doc.ready and fire it when you need (after success callback).

OR

you can download you html to memory, and work with nodes in memory, and when all will be done - just inject it to DOM.

Comment: I don't understand the second approach. But the first paragraph could work for me. I only need to define a function in modal.js and then call that function inside the "complete" function when all the parameters had been set. On the other side, I made the same example with jquery 3.1.1 and it works as expected.

Comment: In second approach you can download your partial html to var, that do smth like that : var $dom = $(yourHtml); and then $dom.... => fill your data. After that all - just $('body').append($dom);